# Why do I get page not found (404) for correct links?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, codeigniter

I have a very strange issue: Google is giving me that some links in my sitemap are not accessible and are giving 404 errors. However, I have tried to open the pages in question and it works fine.

The website has been built using codeigniter and here is [a sample of links](http://widwebway.com/en/solutions)

Now if you try to open the link above, it will work fine. but if you try to `curl -I`:

```
curl -I http://widwebway.com/en/solutions
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

I have made some routes and rewrite rules to exclude the controller name from the URL. In other words, the correct link is

```
curl -I http://widwebway.com/en/widwebway/view/solutions
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 29 Feb 2012 18:05:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Location: http://widwebway.com/en/solutions
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Apache error log gives

```
File does not exist: /var/www/myweb/en, referer: http://widwebway.com/en/solutions
```

my `.htaccess` is:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^ar/widwebway/view/([a-z_]{1,50})[/]*$           /ar/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
  RewriteRule ^en/widwebway/view/([a-z_]{1,50})[/]*$           /en/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
  RewriteRule ^en/widwebway[/]*$           /en/home [L,R=301,NC]
  RewriteRule ^ar/widwebway[/]*$           /ar/home [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Any idea of how comes that the page is there but it gives 404 on curl or Google bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I found:
The browser is actually getting a 404 as well on `http://widwebway.com/en/solutions`

When I go to: `http://widwebway.com/en/widwebway/view/solutions`
I get:

```
Request URL:http://widwebway.com/en/widwebway/view/solutions
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
```

The move is directed to: `http://widwebway.com/en/solutions`
This file `/en/solutions` doesn't actually exist, but with your rewrite rule you're telling the browser to display the contents of `/en/widwebway/view/solutions` when it sees `/en/solutions`

From Chrome Network Inspection:

```
Request URL:http://widwebway.com/en/solutions
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

Try using the PT flag instead. since the /en/solutions isn't a real file. This should get you away from the 404 errors
Example from [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt)

```
Alias /icons /usr/local/apache/icons
RewriteRule /pics/(.+)\.jpg /icons/$1.gif [PT]
```

Comment: by adding [PT] instead of [L,R=301,NC], i start getting 404 for everything... now i removed all of the rewrite rules, and everything above starts to return "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ... my concern was to avoid having duplicate content for google.... do you have any idea how to manage it

Comment: <link rel="canonical" href="http://yourdomain.com/content"> This should go in the header section of your website. put the link to the page you want people to be visiting in the href. As long as you're using the canonical you can have duplicate content everywhere and Google won't care.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like You're missing (or having a malformed) .htaccess file.

Please create a .htaccess file at the root directory and add the following line  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]` to avoid 404 error.

I hope this will help.

Thanks!